# echo coming in new line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

My code is

```
cd /home/XXX/db-new

while read -r line; do


  data=$(echo $line | awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' | awk '{gsub(/\"/,"")};1' | tr -d \'\"   )


  d2=$(echo $data | awk -F, '{print $2}')
  d3=$(echo $data | awk -F, '{print $3}')
  d17=$(echo $data | awk -F, '{print $17}')
  d4=$(echo $data | awk -F, '{print $4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11","$12","$13","$14","$15","$16","$17","$18","$19","$20","$21","$22","$23","$24","$25","$26","$27","$28","$29","$30","$31","$32","$33","$34","$35","$36","$37","$38","$39","$40","$45","$46","$47","$48","$49","$50","$51","$52","$53","$54","$55","$56","$57","$58}')
  d1=$d2+$d3
  d59=$(echo $d2 | cut -d "." -f 2,3)
  d60=$(echo $data | awk -F, '{print $19}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/[[:punct:] ]/,"",$1)} 1' |  sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' )

  echo $d1,$d2,$d4,$d59,$d17,$d60 >> abc.csv
  
done < /home/XXX/db-new/2021-09-04.csv
```

`/home/domainsanalytics/db-new/2021-09-04.csv` is very big so I add only 1st 3 lines.

```
head -3 /home/domainsanalytics/db-new/2021-09-04.csv
"num","domain_name","query_time","create_date","update_date","expiry_date","domain_registrar_id","domain_registrar_name","domain_registrar_whois","domain_registrar_url","registrant_name","registrant_company","registrant_address","registrant_city","registrant_state","registrant_zip","registrant_country","registrant_email","registrant_phone","registrant_fax","administrative_name","administrative_company","administrative_address","administrative_city","administrative_state","administrative_zip","administrative_country","administrative_email","administrative_phone","administrative_fax","technical_name","technical_company","technical_address","technical_city","technical_state","technical_zip","technical_country","technical_email","technical_phone","technical_fax","billing_name","billing_company","billing_address","billing_city","billing_state","billing_zip","billing_country","billing_email","billing_phone","billing_fax","name_server_1","name_server_2","name_server_3","name_server_4","domain_status_1","domain_status_2","domain_status_3","domain_status_4"
"1","accounting-fwppool.com","2021-09-04 00:53:04","2021-08-10","2021-08-10","2022-08-10","303","PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com","whois.publicdomainregistry.com","http://www.publicdomainregistry.com","Micael brown","","4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach, CA 92649","CA","CA","92649","United States","michbrown7654gh@gmail.com","+1.9169136369","","Micael brown","","4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach, CA 92649","CA","CA","92649","United States","michbrown7654gh@gmail.com","+1.9169136369","","Micael brown","","4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach, CA 92649","CA","CA","92649","United States","michbrown7654gh@gmail.com","+1.9169136369","","","","","","","","","","","","ns1.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com","ns2.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com","","","clientTransferProhibited","","",""
"2","xjava.com","2021-09-04 00:53:11","2001-03-06","2021-03-12","2022-03-06","472","Dynadot, LLC","whois.dynadot.com","http://www.dynadot.com","Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot","","PO Box 701","San Mateo","California","94401","United States","xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com","+1.6505854708","","Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot","","PO Box 701","San Mateo","California","94401","United States","xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com","+1.6505854708","","Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot","","PO Box 701","San Mateo","California","94401","United States","xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com","+1.6505854708","","","","","","","","","","","","ns1.sedoparking.com","ns2.sedoparking.com","","","clientTransferProhibited","","",""
```

My code give me result good, but $59 ,$17 and $60 is coming in new line...

> $59 is just tld i am getting,
> $17 is reprint of country,
> $60 is phone number without special characters

**All I want is all in 1 row**

My output is

```
    domain_name+query_time  domain_name create_date update_date expiry_date domain_registrar_id domain_registrar_name   domain_registrar_whois  domain_registrar_url    registrant_name registrant_company  registrant_address  registrant_city registrant_state    registrant_zip  registrant_country  registrant_email    registrant_phone    registrant_fax  administrative_name administrative_company  administrative_address  administrative_city administrative_state    administrative_zip  administrative_country  administrative_email    administrative_phone    administrative_fax  technical_name  technical_company   technical_address   technical_city  technical_state technical_zip   technical_country   technical_email technical_phone technical_fax   billing_state   billing_zip billing_country billing_email   billing_phone   billing_fax name_server_1   name_server_2   name_server_3   name_server_4   domain_status_1 domain_status_2 domain_status_3 domain_status_4
    domain_name registrant_country                                                                                                                                                                                                      
accounting-fwppool.com+2021-09-04 00:53:04  accounting-fwppool.com  10/08/21    10/08/21    10/08/22    303 PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com whois.publicdomainregistry.com  http://www.publicdomainregistry.com Micael brown        4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach CA 92649 CA  CA  92649   United States   michbrown7654gh@gmail.com   1.916913637     Micael brown        4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach CA 92649 CA  CA  92649   United States   michbrown7654gh@gmail.com   1.916913637     Micael brown        4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach CA 92649 CA  CA  92649   United States   michbrown7654gh@gmail.com   1.916913637                             ns1.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com  ns2.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com          clientTransferProhibited            
    com United States   19169136369                                                                                                                                                                                                 
xjava.com+2021-09-04 00:53:11   xjava.com   06/03/01    12/03/21    06/03/22    472 Dynadot LLC whois.dynadot.com   http://www.dynadot.com  Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot       PO Box 701  San Mateo   California  94401   United States   xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com   1.650585471     Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot       PO Box 701  San Mateo   California  94401   United States   xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com   1.650585471     Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot       PO Box 701  San Mateo   California  94401   United States   xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com   1.650585471                             ns1.sedoparking.com ns2.sedoparking.com         clientTransferProhibited            
    com United States   16505854708                                                                                                                                                                                                 
accuratetactics.com+2021-09-04 00:53:14 accuratetactics.com 26/08/20    30/08/21    26/08/21    1660    Domainshype.com Inc.    whois.domainshype.com   http://www.domainshype.com  This Domain For Sale Worldwide 339 222 5132 Buydomains.com  738 Main Street #389    Waltham Massachusetts   2451    United States   brokerage@buydomains.com    1.339222513 1.78183928  This Domain For Sale Worldwide 339 222 5132 Buydomains.com  738 Main Street #389    Waltham Massachusetts   2451    United States   brokerage@buydomains.com    1.339222513 1.78183928  This Domain For Sale Worldwide 339 222 5132 Buydomains.com  738 Main Street #389    Waltham Massachusetts   2451    United States   brokerage@buydomains.com    1.339222513 1.78183928                          dns7.parkpage.foundationapi.com dns8.parkpage.foundationapi.com         OK          
    com United States   13392225132                                                                                                                                                                                                 
vej.com+2021-09-04 00:53:16 vej.com 16/09/99    31/08/21    16/09/23    128 DomainRegistry.com Inc. nswhois.domainregistry.com  http://www.domainregistry.com   Scottcraft Label Co.    Scottcraft Label Co.    c/o Admin Svcs. PO Box 145  Marlton NJ  8053    United States   itadmin@scottcraftlabel.com 1.215870212     IT Admin MS 445 Scottcraft Label Co.    c/o Admin Svcs. PO Box 145  Marlton NJ  8053    United States   itadmin@scottcraftlabel.com 1.215870212     IT Admin MS 445 Scottcraft Label Co.    c/o Admin Svcs. PO Box 145  Marlton NJ  8053    United States   itadmin@scottcraftlabel.com 1.215870212                             colohost1.domainregistry.com    cs03.domainregistry.com         clientDeleteProhibited  clientTransferProhibited    clientUpdateProhibited  
    com United States   12158702120                                                                                                                                                                                                 
accutekware.com+2021-09-04 00:53:24 accutekware.com 26/08/03    26/08/21    26/08/21    303 PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com whois.publicdomainregistry.com  http://www.publicdomainregistry.com R Benedict  Accutek Systems Inc PO Box 591125   Houston Texas   77259   United States   rbeny09@hotmail.com 1.281461701     R Benedict  Accutek Systems Inc PO Box 591125   Houston Texas   77259   United States   rbeny09@hotmail.com 1.281461701     R Benedict  Accutek Systems Inc PO Box 591125   Houston Texas   77259   United States   rbeny09@hotmail.com 1.281461701                             dns10.parkpage.foundationapi.com    dns11.parkpage.foundationapi.com            clientTransferProhibited            
    com United States   12814617007                                                                                                                                                                                                 
crmxon.com+2021-09-04 00:53:27  crmxon.com  04/09/20    04/11/20    04/09/21    303 PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com whois.publicdomainregistry.com  http://www.publicdomainregistry.com GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked Newcastleupon Tyne(Cityof)  GDPR Masked United Kingdom  gdpr-masking@gdpr-masked.com    GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked gdpr-masking@gdpr-masked.com    GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked GDPR Masked gdpr-masking@gdpr-masked.com    GDPR Masked GDPR Masked                         ns1.edagent.com ns2.edagent.com ns3.edagent.com ns4.edagent.com clientTransferProhibited            
    com United Kingdom
```

Expected output

```
    domain_name+query_time domain_name create_date update_date expiry_date domain_registrar_id domain_registrar_name domain_registrar_whois domain_registrar_url registrant_name registrant_company registrant_address registrant_city registrant_state registrant_zip registrant_country registrant_email registrant_phone registrant_fax administrative_name administrative_company administrative_address administrative_city administrative_state administrative_zip administrative_country administrative_email administrative_phone administrative_fax technical_name technical_company technical_address technical_city technical_state technical_zip technical_country technical_email technical_phone technical_fax billing_state billing_zip billing_country billing_email billing_phone billing_fax name_server_1 name_server_2 name_server_3 name_server_4 domain_status_1 domain_status_2 domain_status_3 domain_status_4 domain_name registrant_country
    accounting-fwppool.com+2021-09-04 00:53:04 accounting-fwppool.com 10/08/21 10/08/21 10/08/22 303 PDR Ltd. d/b/a PublicDomainRegistry.com whois.publicdomainregistry.com http://www.publicdomainregistry.com Micael brown 4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach CA 92649 CA CA 92649 United States michbrown7654gh@gmail.com 1.91691364 Micael brown 4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach CA 92649 CA CA 92649 United States michbrown7654gh@gmail.com 1.91691364 Micael brown 4941 Maui Cir Huntington Beach CA 92649 CA CA 92649 United States michbrown7654gh@gmail.com 1.91691364 ns1.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com ns2.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com clientTransferProhibited com United States 1.9169E+10
    xjava.com+2021-09-04 00:53:11 xjava.com 06/03/01 12/03/21 06/03/22 472 Dynadot LLC whois.dynadot.com http://www.dynadot.com Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot PO Box 701 San Mateo California 94401 United States xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com 1.65058547 Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot PO Box 701 San Mateo California 94401 United States xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com 1.65058547 Super Privacy Service LTD c/o Dynadot PO Box 701 San Mateo California 94401 United States xjava.com@superprivacyservice.com 1.65058547 ns1.sedoparking.com ns2.sedoparking.com clientTransferProhibited com United States 1.6506E+10
    accuratetactics.com+2021-09-04 00:53:14 accuratetactics.com 26/08/20 30/08/21 26/08/21 1660 Domainshype.com Inc. whois.domainshype.com http://www.domainshype.com This Domain For Sale Worldwide 339 222 5132 Buydomains.com 738 Main Street #389 Waltham Massachusetts 2451 United States brokerage@buydomains.com 1.33922251 1.78183928 This Domain For Sale Worldwide 339 222 5132 Buydomains.com 738 Main Street #389 Waltham Massachusetts 2451 United States brokerage@buydomains.com 1.33922251 1.78183928 This Domain For Sale Worldwide 339 222 5132 Buydomains.com 738 Main Street #389 Waltham Massachusetts 2451 United States brokerage@buydomains.com 1.33922251 1.78183928 dns7.parkpage.foundationapi.com dns8.parkpage.foundationapi.com OK com United States 1.3392E+10
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output for these 3 lines in text format?

Comment: @anubhava I just add in the question.

Comment: The screenshot does not help. We would have to see the content of `abc.csv`. I suggest that you do a `head -n 2 abc.csv` and a `head -n 2 abc.csv | xxd` after creating the file and show the output here.

Comment: Do check for presence of DOS line ending `\n` in your CSV. Also note that you can do all this in a single awk code instead of a while loop with so many awk invocations

Comment: @anubhava DOS new lines are `\r\n`. \@CorOmnes you can check that with `file your.csv` and see the new line type

Comment: I meant `\r` not `\n`

Comment: Using a shell loop to manipulate text is an anti-pattern, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). If you'd like help doing whatever it is you're trying to do the right way then [edit] your question to include a [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Comment: As the [bash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) you used in your question instructs you to do - copy/paste your shell script(s) into https://shellcheck.net and fix the problems that tool tells you about before posting here if you still have a problem afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting single `awk` script to process all the data:

Staring with this:

#### `script.awk`

```
BEGIN{FS="\",\"|\"[[:space:]]*$|^[[:space:]]*\""; OFS=" "}
{
  $1=$1; # recalculate fields
  
  # num field start from $2 
  arr[1] = $3 "+" $4;
  arr[2] = $4;
  
  arr[4] = $5;
  # right append to arr[4] fields 6-41
  for (i = 6; i <= 41; i++) arr[4] = arr[4] "," $i;
  # right append to arr[4] fields 46-59
  for (i = 46; i <= 59; i++) arr[4] = arr[4] "," $i;
  
  arr[17] =  $18;
  
  arr[59 ] = $3;
  # in 3rd field remove text after first "."
  sub(/\..*$/,"",arr[59]);

  # remove all punctuations and digits from 20th field
  gsub(/[[:punct:]]|[[:digit:]]*/,"",$20);
  arr[60] = $20;

  # output to stdout
  print arr[1],arr[2],arr[4],arr[59],arr[17],arr[60];
}
```

#### Running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.csv > output.csv
```

Did not test since the sample data did not contain numeric values.